# Can T-47 airspeeders fly in space?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, obi-wan-kenobi-2022

Are the T-47 airspeeders (from *Episode V*, on the  planet Hoth and also seen in Part IV of *Obi-Wan Kenobi*) able to fly in space in a similar manner to spacecraft?

[image: T-47 airspeeder]

Comment: ***Air***speeder...

Comment: The T-47 Airspeeder is a speeder, not a spaceship.

Answer (score 14):

### The max flight envelope for the T-47 airspeeder is 175-250m (see below)

The (canon) reference book [*Star Wars: The Rebel Files*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rebel_Files) lists the 'flight ceiling' of the modified T-47 Airspeeder as 175 metres.

[image: Star Wars: The Rebel Files, T-47 Airspeeder]

Interestingly, an earlier factbook *[Star Wars Complete Cross-Sections: The Spacecraft and Vehicles of the Entire Star Wars Saga](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Complete_Cross-Sections)* lists the flight ceiling' of the snow-modified T-47 airspeeder as **175 km(!) or 108.7 miles**

[image: Star Wars Complete Cross-Sections: The Spacecraft and Vehicles of the Entire Star Wars Saga]

Obviously this conflicts violently with the info in other sources such as the [Star Wars: Official Fact File Vol. 1 #28](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Official_Star_Wars_Fact_File_28) which states that the envelope can be pushed *to as much as 250M*. It's likely that the *Complete Cross-Sections* book was meant to say 175m, not 175**k**m

> *In its civilian incarnation, the T-47 could manage a top speed of 650 kilometres per hour, but skilled Rebel engineers were able to up the velocity to 1,000 kph for the snowspeeder variant. The craft's optimal combat speed was 570 kph, making it slow enough for a pilot to fly it well, but fast enough for an enemy gunner to have difficulty tracking it.*
>
> ***The craft performed best when flying at low altitudes, but could climb to a height of 250 metres if necessary.** Above all, the snowspeeders were swift and highly agile, with forward thrust provided by twin repulsorlift drives and high-powered afterburners. With only a layer of armour plating and no shield generators for protection, a snowspeeder's crew would rely on speed and manoeuvrability to endure the battle.*

Comment: Just note that in comparison, the SR-71 has a flight ceiling of 90,000 feet, which is **only** ~28 km. 175 KM is practically space flight.

Answer (score 7):

## No.

According to the book [*Star Wars Encyclopedia of Starfighters and Other Vehicles*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Encyclopedia_of_Starfighters_and_Other_Vehicles), the snowspeeder is a ***low-altitude*** vehicle:

> "These **low-altitude ships** were never meant for combat purposes."
> *(emphasis mine)*

[image: Star Wars Encyclopedia of Startfighters and other vehicles, p.20]

Comment: "...never built for combat purposes". Then what are the two gigantic laser cannons for, with a dedicated tail gunner to operate them? They're both clearly integral to the design. I get that scouting is it's primary role, but it's clearly built for combat purposes.

Answer (score 3):

From the film only, it certainly appears that the T-47s (which are not identified with the speeder in the *The Empire Strikes Back* itself—but let's take it as given that they are the same) had to be loaded onto transports, rather than flown off world (the way the X-wings were).

> MEDICAL DROID:  Sir, it will take quite a while to evacuate the T-forty-sevens.
>
> LUKE:  Well, forget the heavy equipment.  There's plenty of time to get the smaller modules on the transports.
>
> MEDICAL DROID:  Take care, sir.
>
> LUKE:  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although not necessarily a solid proof, the German version of Wookieepedia (Jedipedia) mentions a maximum flying height of 175 meters ([source](https://www.jedipedia.net/wiki/T-47_Luftgleiter#legends)).

> Die beste Leistung erbrachte der Gleiter bei niedriger Flughöhe, gleichwohl er technisch in der Lage war, bis auf 175 Meter aufzusteigen.
>
> *The best performance was achieved by the glider at low altitudes, although technically able to ascend to 175 meters.* (Google translate)

That together with the fact that it is always termed as an airspeeder ([starwars.com](https://www.starwars.com/databank/snowspeeder)) or an atmospheric vehicle ([Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/T-47_airspeeder/Legends)) suggests that it is not capable of space flight.

Answer (score -2):

YES- The snowspeeders were the mass produced civilian model of the T-47 - limited production but used by the rebel alliance was a T-47 C-Wing starfighter

https://swfanon.fandom.com/wiki/T-47_C-Wing

Comment: Not the same kind.

Comment: Am I understanding that site correctly? It's fan fiction? I'm not aware of any canon or even legends references to this variant.